# drawableで指定したレイアウト(shapeタグなど)の背景などの動的設定について

Tags: android

ボタンなどの背景色を変えるには
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
などで出来ますが、buttonのレイアウトをdrawableで指定している場合、上の記述だと
drawable指定が無効になります（Radiusなど無視され、ただの赤ボタンになる）

なのでGradientDrawableで背景情報を得て、変更しようとしましたが上手くいきません

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        // これだとxmlファイルのdrawable指定が無効になる
        // view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        GradientDrawable background = (GradientDrawable)view.getBackground();
        background.setColor(Color.RED);

    }
}
```

activity_main.xmlに記述したボタンレイアウトはこんな感じです

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background" />
```

drawableのbutton_background.xml（角は丸く、灰色に設定してある。このカラーの部分を変えたい）

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="#555555" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

エミュは立ち上がり、ボタンを押すとエラーが出ます

どの部分が間違っているでしょうか？
出来ればコード修正してもらうとありがたいです

また回答してくださいましたsetBackgroundResource(リソース）でもいいのですが
drawableファイルの　solid android:color="@color/COLORNAME"　だけの動的変更はできるのでしょうか？

Comment: ボタンが押された場合の状態などは、一般的には[StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)を使うのですが、コードで動的に制御しなければならない理由があるのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。ボタンゲームでたくさんの色ボタンオブジェクトを考えてます。StateListDrawable、ColorDrawableなど参考になります。

Answer (score 1):

Javaのコードのみで制御する場合はこんな感じです。一旦Drawableを作って、それを適用します。この例の場合、color_flagの値で色々なカラーに変更出来ます。

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button bt;
int color_flag = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
bt.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
drawable.mutate();
drawable.setShape(0);// 0がRECTANGLE
drawable.setCornerRadius(5);
if (color_flag == 0) {
drawable.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF3300"));//赤
} else if (color_flag == 1) {
drawable.setColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));//青
} else {
drawable.setColor(Color.parseColor("#555555"));//元の色
}
bt.setBackground(drawable);
}

}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。　
１つのボタンの場合はsetBackgroundResourceでOKですね。　
書いてくれたbutton_background_pressed.xmlの<solid android:color="@color/button_pressed" />だけの動的変更はできるのでしょうか？　

多数の色を用意したい場合、全ボタンをdrawableのbutton_background.xml（または　button_background_pressed.xml）で一括管理したいので、ボタンの色を変えるとなるとdrawableファイルを各色ごとファイルを用意する必要が出てきますよね。　
なのでこのdrawableファイルの中を変更できるのかなと考えてます。　
説明が分かりにくかったらすみません；

Comment: 回答を修正しました。大量のカラーを扱うのであれば、このようにすると良いかと思います。xmlで一括管理するのは恐らく厳しいと思いますので、必要に応じてonClickの中身をユーティリティクラスに置き換えるなどすると１つのファイルで管理できます。

Comment: 参考になります。ありがとうございます。mutate()がキモですね